# Is the intersection of an arbitrary collection of semirings a semiring?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A **semiring** (of sets) is a nonempty class $\mathcal{P}$ of subsets of the whole space $X$ that is closed under intersections and is such that any difference of two sets in $\mathcal{P}$ can be expressed as a finite disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal{P}$.

**Motivation for this question:** for any class $\mathcal{E}$ of subsets of the whole space $X$, does there exist a unique smallest semiring containing $\mathcal{E}$? In other words, does there exist such a thing as *the semiring generated by* $\mathcal{E}$? I believe the answer is "no," but I don't really have a good reason why.

**The actual question:** Normally, to prove the existence of rings (or fields, I'll just stick to rings for simplicity) generated by a set $\mathcal{E}$, we first show that the intersection of an arbitrary collection of rings is again a ring. My hunch is that this result does not hold for semirings, and is the reason why there (possibly) does not exist such a thing as a semiring generated by $\mathcal{E}$.

Let $\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$ be a semiring for every $\gamma$ in some index set $\Gamma$. Define $\mathcal{P} = \cap \{\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}: \gamma \in \Gamma\}$. Then if $E, F \in \mathcal{P}$, we have that $E,F \in \mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$ for every $\gamma$. Then by the definition of semiring for each $\gamma$ there exists a disjoint collection of sets $\{E_{n_{\gamma}}\} \in \mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$ such that $E-F = \cup E_{n_{\gamma}}$ (for each $\gamma$ this sequence may be different).

But for some reason I'm having trouble seeing why I can't take this disjoint sequence $\{E_{n_{\gamma}}\}$ to be *common* across $\gamma$. If I can, then it follows that an intersection of an arbitrary collection of semirings is a semiring, and then it follows that generated semirings exist. But I'm becoming convinced that they don't exist. Can anyone point out where I'm tripping up?

Comment: Why does the set of half open intervals contain any open intervals?

Comment: Oops. You're absolutely right. It doesn't. Thanks for catching that... I need more coffee.

Comment: I believe the collection of finite intervals (whether open, closed, or half and half) is a semi ring, but I have no idea whether it should be minimal. The picture is very chaos for me, as I don't know where to start argue given an uncountable set. Maybe some deep set theory will be involved and the counterexample will be pathetic...

Comment: Only the collection of half-open intervals (all closed on the same side) is a semiring. The set of all open intervals and the set of all closed intervals are not semirings.

Comment: In your argument, how can you say that $E_{n_ {\lambda}}$ belong to each $P_{\lambda}$? Surely, you could have different $E_{n_{\lambda}}$ for different $P_{\lambda}$.

Comment: @Alexander that is exactly what I meant: for each $\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$ there is some sequence $\{E_{n_{\gamma}}\}$. My question is: can I take these to be common across the $\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$? Let me add a note to make it less confusing.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. But is there any reason a priori that one might expect to be able to take the $\{E_{n_{\lambda}}\}$ to be common across $P_{\lambda}$?

Comment: @gogurt, I mean the collection of them all, which is a semiring containing all the finite open intervals.

Comment: @dentisDark Ah, sorry. I misinterpreted your comment. You're absolutely right.

Comment: @Alexander I don't have any solid reasons. It just feels like one might be able to, since the differenced sets $E,F$ are in all of the $\mathcal{P}_{\gamma}$. Part of my question is how to flesh this out a bit more...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then we let $S_1=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2,3,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{4\}\}, S_2=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2,3,4\}, \{3,4\}, \{2\}\}$. Both are semirings but their intersection is not.

Comment: Ah, sometimes the simplest example is best. Thanks!